# Angular CDK: Apply animations to Angular custom stepper on step change

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-animations, angular-cdk

I am stuck with animating the step change of the Angular material custom stepper using the CDK.
I have followed the [tutorial](https://material.angular.io/guide/creating-a-custom-stepper-using-the-cdk-stepper) on how to implement the custom stepper.

I have the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-stepper-example-solution?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-stepper%2Fmy-stepper.component.html)

My template looks like:

```
<section class="container">
 <header>
    <h2>Step {{selectedIndex + 1}}/{{steps.length}}</h2>
    <div>
      <button class="pure-button" cdkStepperPrevious>&larr;</button>
      <button
      class="pure-button"
      *ngFor="let step of steps; let i = index;"
      [ngClass]="{'pure-button-primary': selectedIndex === i}"
      (click)="onClick(i)"
  >
    Step {{i + 1}}
      </button>
      <button class="pure-button" cdkStepperNext>&rarr;</button>
     </div>
   </header>

 <div [@stepTransition]="_getAnimationDirection(current)" *ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index">
  <div  [ngTemplateOutlet]="selected.content"></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

And my component TS file look like:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CdkStepper } from '@angular/cdk/stepper';
import {
     trigger,
     state,
     style,
     animate,
     transition,
 } from '@angular/animations';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-my-stepper',
   templateUrl: './my-stepper.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./my-stepper.component.css'],
   providers: [{ provide: CdkStepper, useExisting: MyStepperComponent }],
  animations: [trigger('stepTransition', [
      state('previous', style({transform: 'translate3d(-100%, 0, 0)', visibility: 'hidden'})),
      state('current', style({transform: 'none', visibility: 'visible'})),
      state('next', style({transform: 'translate3d(100%, 0, 0)', visibility: 'hidden'})),
      transition('* => *', animate('500ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)'))
   ])]
})
 export class MyStepperComponent extends CdkStepper implements OnInit {
    current = 0;

    onClick(index: number): void {
    this.current = index;
     this.selectedIndex = index;
  }

  ngOnInit() {   
      console.log(this._getFocusIndex())
   }

}
```

The animation only works for the last step, the reason is that the animation state(previous, current, next)value does not change onClick.

How can I achieve this? any idea is much appreciated, thanks.

**UPDATE**
Check the stackblitz repo for the latest code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-stepper-example-fe6hgc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fmy-stepper%2Fmy-stepper.component.ts) you have the following html:

```html
<div *ngFor="let step of _steps; let i = index"
     [@stepTransition]="_getAnimationDirection(i)" 
     [attr.tabindex]="selectedIndex === i ? 0 : null"
     [id]="_getStepContentId(i)"
     (@stepTransition.done)="_animationDone.next($event)"
     [attr.aria-labelledby]="_getStepLabelId(i)"
     [attr.aria-expanded]="selectedIndex === i">
    <ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="selected.content">
    </ng-container> 
</div>
```

I think the main problem here is in this line: `<div [ngTemplateOutlet]="selected.content"></div>`

You create a `div` for each `step`, and every `div` will contain the same `selected.content`. So all the styles applied to the parent `div` (`transform` and `visibility`) will also apply to the `selected.content` which will lead to an ambiguous behavior.

If you replace it with `<div [ngTemplateOutlet]="step.content"></div>`, you will start seeing all your images, but they will be placed one under another.

This happens because of the css [visibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) property:

> it shows or hides an element **without changing the layout** of a
>   document.

So I suggest you to add `position: absolute;` to your steps.

Take a look at the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cdk-stepper-example-ef7mzs) with these improvements

Comment: the last image is slid the first time the first image is being rendered, is it possible to have the last image not visible at all the first time?

Comment: @Teebo yes, you can add `transition(':enter', animate(0)),` to your animations before this line: `transition('* => *', animate('500ms cubic-bezier(0.35, 0, 0.25, 1)'))`. It will skip the initial animation. Check the updated stackblitz.